# Access to an Array inside a Post Array with Sanity using next.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I have an issue here trying to access a Post array that has inside a categories array. So if I console.log the data I see something like this:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      _createdAt: '2021-10-23T05:02:26Z',
      _type: 'post',
      _updatedAt: '2021-10-23T23:28:09Z',
      body: [Array],
      categories: [Array], <<<<-- this is the one I need to access
      mainImage: [Object],
      publishedAt: '2021-10-23T18:30:00.000Z',
      slug: [Object],
      title: 'Post Name title goes here'
    }
   .
   .
   .
  ]
}
```

I need to access the categories Array inside my Post Array,but I'm having a really hard time trying to access it. I currently tried something like this:

```
 <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
  {posts.map(
    ({
      _id,
      title = "",
      slug = "",
      _createdAt = "",
      mainImage = "",
      categories = "",
    }) =>
      slug && (
        <div className="shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-white pb-5" key={_id}>
          <div className="px-6 py-4 text-left">
            <div className="flex flex-row mt-4 items-center">
              {categories && (
                <ul className="inline-flex my-3" style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                  {categories.map((category) => (
                    <li key={category}>
                      <span
                        className="mx-2 
                          items-center
                          justify-center
                          px-2
                          py-1
                          text-xs
                          font-bold"
                      >
                        {category}
                      </span>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  )}
</div>;
```

when I do this I get the following error:

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_key, _ref, _type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

I even tried to do something like this:

```
{posts.categories.map((category) => (
    <li key={category}>
      <span
        className="mx-2 
            items-center
            justify-center
            px-2
            py-1
            text-xs
            font-bold"
      >
        {category}
      </span>
    </li>
  ));
}
```

But still no luck. Any ideas of what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it looks like `categories` is an array of references. You'll want to resolve the references in your GROQ query (something like `"categories": categories[]->`) and then on your front end, you'll need to use *properties* of each `category` (created when you map over `categories`) rather than the whole object itself. You'll want to map over `categories` as you've done, but inside the map callback function you won't ever directly refer to the whole object.

Rather than:

```
{posts.categories.map((category) => (
    <li key={category}>
      <span>
        {category}
      </span>
    </li>
  ));
}
```

you'll want to do something like (assuming a `text` property exists):

```
{posts.categories.map((category) => (
    <li key={category._id}>
      <span>
        {category.text}
      </span>
    </li>
  ));
}
```

Comment: ur the maaan thanks!!!

Comment: Thank you very much. You save me an hour searching through Sanity forum!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an array of arrays?

```
const arrayOfArrayOfCategories = posts.map(post => post.categories);
```

If you want to access the first post's categories:

```
const { categories } = posts[0];
```

Comment: I totally get this, but I can't seem to apply it to my JSX code, as I showed up in my question. Any idea how could I apply this?

Answer (score 0):

Always best to split code up to make it easier. I would create seperate component for Post that takes in `post` as a prop. Then import it where you need to.

**Post.js**

```
function Post({ post }) {
  const { categories } = post;

  function renderCategories() {
    return categories.map((category) => {
      return <span>{category}</span>;
    });
  }
  return <div>{renderCategories()}</div>;
}

export default Post;
```

**App.js**

```
import Post from "./Post";

function App() {
  const posts = [
    {
      _createdAt: "2021-10-23T05:02:26Z",
      _type: "post",
      _updatedAt: "2021-10-23T23:28:09Z",
      body: [Array],
      categories: ["categoiry", "sfsdfd", "eosiefoise", "dseuhse"],
      mainImage: [Object],
      publishedAt: "2021-10-23T18:30:00.000Z",
      slug: [Object],
      title: "Post Name title goes here",
    },
    {
      _createdAt: "2021-10-23T05:02:26Z",
      _type: "post",
      _updatedAt: "2021-10-23T23:28:09Z",
      body: [Array],
      categories: ["categoiry", "sfsdfd", "eosiefoise", "dseuhse"],
      mainImage: [Object],
      publishedAt: "2021-10-23T18:30:00.000Z",
      slug: [Object],
      title: "Post Name title goes here",
    },
    {
      _createdAt: "2021-10-23T05:02:26Z",
      _type: "post",
      _updatedAt: "2021-10-23T23:28:09Z",
      body: [Array],
      categories: ["categoiry", "sfsdfd", "eosiefoise", "dseuhse"],
      mainImage: [Object],
      publishedAt: "2021-10-23T18:30:00.000Z",
      slug: [Object],
      title: "Post Name title goes here",
    },
  ];

  function renderPosts() {
    return posts.map((post) => {
      return <Post post={post} />;
    });
  }

  return <div>{renderPosts()}</div>;
}
```